# Adding a component to jPanel java

Tags: java, netbeans

i'm trying to add a jtable component to my jPanel but i am unable to see it. What am i doing wrong?.

```
table gui = new table(data,colum); 
mainPanel.add(gui.table);

class table extends JFrame
{
    public JTable table; 

    public table(Vector data, Vector colum)
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        table = new JTable(data,colum);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(900,10));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: This is confusing. Why are you adding stuff to a JFrame and then adding it to a different JPanel? What is the motivation behind this? You know that you can only visualize a component once, not twice. If you want the same JTable to appear more than once, then  you will need to create multiple JTables and have them share the same table model.

Comment: I'm rather new to java and still trying to figure things out however i guess you are referring to the line 'add(scrollPane);' i thought that this is for the jtable scrolling?. Then i initialize the table class and add its table component to the main jpanel. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: I don't actually see a JPanel in your code.  Can you clarify that issue?

Comment: I've used netbeans GUI to create a basic interface. I am now trying to learn how to code from scratch. But anyways, the generated code is this for the panel "mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();" . I am able to change the color of the background so i know that its the correct panel

Comment: Oh, I see.  `mainPanel` is a JPanel.   There is no situation under which you want to add a JFrame to a JPanel.  But that is what you are doing.  The class `table` extends `JFrame`, yet you are adding it to a JPanel.   So you are adding a JFrame to a JPanel.  Don't do that!

Comment: So what modifications do i need to make in the table class?. If i remove 'extends jframe' i am unable to 'add(scrollPane)'. And even so it still does not show?

Comment: What you should do is read the Swing tutorials. Most of this stuff is well explained there and is where most of us learned our Swing.

Comment: Im going though them and i am unsure of where i am going wrong hence the question being posted ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending JFrame seems odd; you don't use any of the top level container capabilities.  Here's an example that extends JPanel, with a main() that drops the panel into a JFrame.

--Edited to accept an existing JPanel

```
public class TablePanel
{
  public static void addTableToPanel(JPanel jPanel, Vector rowData, Vector columnNames)
  {
    JTable jTable = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
    jTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);
    jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));

    jPanel.add(jScrollPane);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        Vector cols = new Vector();
        Vector rows = new Vector();
        Vector row1 = new Vector();

        cols.add("A");
        cols.add("B");
        cols.add("C");
        row1.add("1");
        row1.add("2");
        row1.add("3");
        rows.add(row1);
        rows.add(row1.clone());
        rows.add(row1.clone());
        rows.add(row1.clone());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        TablePanel.addTableToPanel(jPanel, rows, cols);

        frame.getContentPane().add(jPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you add the table you have created to an existing Jpanel. Lets assume have this line mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel(); . You want to add your table, to the mainPanel , how do you do it? (because this is the issue that i'm having, its not being displayed). Your example displays the table in a new window

Comment: I edited the code to accept an existing JPanel rather than extend it.  If you're using an existing JPanel, I'd advise you to pay attention to  its layout.  If you don't see your table or it appears in a strange way, it's likely a layout issue.